# How to create solvable equations with algebraic fractions?

Tags: quadratics, fractions

I came across this simple algebraic fractions question:

$\frac{8}{x+3}+\frac{3}{x+8}=1$

After a bit of manipulation you are left with a difference of two squares and it is easily solvable.

I then wondered how these questions are made, so had a go at creating a new one and it has been surprisingly difficult.

My first thought was to work backwards from a factorisable quadratic, but I hit a dead end.

My attempt now is to begin with something in the form:

$\frac{a}{x+b}+\frac{b}{x+a}=1$

Which leads to:

$0=x^2+ab-a^2-b^2$

So my question is, how to pick values of a and b so that this will be factorisable, or more specifically so that it will be a difference of two squares? i.e:

$ab-a^2-b^2=-n^2$ for some integer n.

Comment: If you plot $a^2+b^2-ab=1$ in the $ab$ plane you'll get an ellipse, and you are looking for rational points on that ellipse.  You can approach that the same way one approaches the Pythagorean Theorem (which comes down to hunting for rational points on $a^2+b^2=1$).

Comment: The two terms on the left of your equation are the same.  I am sure that is not what you meant.  Please correct.

Answer (score 1):

To elaborate on lulu's perfect answer:

$a^2+b^2-ab=n^2\iff x^2+y^2-xy=1$, where $x=a/n, y=b/n$.

Now, to parametrize the points of this ellipse, you can start from the point $I=(1,0)$, and then intersect a line of $\mathbb{R}^2$, passing through $I$. The equation of such a line has the form $y=t(x-1)$. Plugging into the ellipse equation yields $x^2+t^2(x-1)^2- tx(x-1)-1=0$, that is $(x-1)(x+1+t^2(x-1)-tx)=0$.

The case $x=1$ will give the point $I$. If $x\neq 1$, little algebraic computations yield $x=\dfrac{t^2-1}{t^2-t+1}, y=\dfrac{t^2-2t}{t^2-t+1}$.

If you take for $t$ any rational value, you will get rational points on your ellipse (in fact, one may convince ourselves that we get all of them).

**Side remark.** Letting $t$ go to $+\infty$ yield the missing point $I$.

Multiplying $x,y$ by a suitable integer $n$ (for example a denominator of $x,y$), you will get integers $a,b$ as you want.

An easy infinite family of examples would be $a=m^2-1, b=m^2-2m$, where $m$ is an arbitrary integer.

A little algebra shows that  $(m^2-1)^2+(m^2-2m)^2-(m^2-1)(m^2-2m)=(m^2-m+1)^2$, so for $a=m^2-1, b=m^2-2m$, you may take $n=m^2-m+1$.

Note that the case $a=8$ and $b=3$ corresponds to $m=3$.